# How to retrieve option store label?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, attribute-options

Could someone teach me how to retrieve the option label for current store view? There is a table `eav_attribute_option_value` where these information are already stored, but I don't know what model I must use.

Answer (score 2):

**Step1:** First get the attribute id, for example by attibute code from the `eav/entity_attribute` model:

```
$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', $YourattributeCode)
```

**Step2:** Using the attribute id, load the `catalog/entity_attribute` attribute model:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getResource()
                ->getAttribute($attributeModel->getId());
```

**Step3:** set the current store id:

```
    $attribute
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```

**Step4**: get the option value:

```
/* @var $attribute Mage_Catalog_Model_Entity_Attribute */
if ($attribute) :
$options = array();
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions() as $optionId => $optionValue) {
        if (is_array($optionValue)) {
            $options[] = $optionValue;
        } else {
            $options[] = array(
                'value' => $optionId,
                'label' => $optionValue
            );
        }
    }
}
endif;
```